# format text fields created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new so I'll appreciate some help here. please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQgGF/2/).

```
 $(function () {

var input = $('<input type="text" />');

$('#qty').bind('blur', function () {
    var n = this.value || 0;
    if (n + 1) {
        setFields(n);
    }
});

function setFields(n) {
    $('#newFields').html("");
    $('#newFields').append("<table>");


    //to create rows and columns
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            var somestr = "Sample ";
            var num = i + 1;
            $('#newFields').append("<td>" + somestr + num + ":" + "</td>");
            $('#newFields').append("<td>");
            var newInput = input.clone();
            var newFields1 = $('');
            newFields1 = newFields1.add(newInput);
            newInput.appendTo('#newFields');
            $('#newFields').after("</td>");
        }
        $('#newFields').after("</tr>");
    }
   }

 });
```

I'll like to have the input text field appear on the right column (so it should be [column 1]"Sample #" [column 2] input text field, with "Sample 2" and another text field appearing on the next row and so forth). Been trying but couldn't get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try appending new rows to the existing table by targeting the table itself on the appendTo() method. You don't need to add a new table and, as you haven't been closing the table off with `</table>` this isn't working at present anyway.